# Storing and querying a large amount of data

Tags: python, mysql, bigdata, mysql-python

I have a large amount of data around 50GB worth in a csv which i want to analyse purposes of ML. It is however way to large to fit in Python. I ideally want to use mySQL because querying is easier. Can anyone offer a host of tips for me to look into. This can be anything from:

1. How to store it in the first place, i realise i probably can't load it in all at once, would i do it iteratively? If so what things can i look into for this? In addition i've heard about indexing, would that really speed up queries on such a massive data set?
2. Are there better technologies out there to handle this amount of data and still be able to query and do feature engineering quickly. What i eventually feed into my algorithm should be able to be done in Python but i need query and do some feature engineering before i get my data set that is ready to be analysed.

I'd really appreciate any advice this all needs to be done on personal computer! Thanks!!

Comment: Use Talend Open Studio - it's well suited to this kind of task imo

Comment: What is "ML"?  Any database can, for example, SUM a column in a zillion-row table.  But if the "analysis" is too complex, then that is not viable.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone offer a host of tips for me to look into

Gladly!

- Look at the CSV file first line to see if there is a header. You'd need to create a table with the same fields (and type of data)
- One of the fields might seem unique per line and can be used **later** to find the line. That's your candidate for `PRIMARY KEY`. Otherwise add an `AUTO-INCREMENT` field as `PRIMARY KEY`
- `INDEX`es are used to **later** search for data. Whatever fields you feel you will be searching/filtering on later should have some sort of `INDEX`. You can always add them later.
- INDEXes can combine multiple fields if they are often searched together
- In order to read in the data, you have 2 ways:
- 1. Use `LOAD DATA INFILE` [Load Data Infile Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)
- 2. Write your own script: The best technique is to create a `prepared statement` for the
     `INSERT` command. Then read your CSV line by line (in a loop), split the fields
     into variables and `execute` the prepared statement with this line's
     values
- You will benefit from a web page designed to search the data. Depends on who needs to use it.

Hope this gives you some ideas

Answer (score 0):

That's depend on what you have, you can use Apache spark and then use their SQL feature, spark SQL gives you the possibility to write SQL queries in your dataset, but for best performance you need a distributed mode(you can use it in a local machine but the result is limited) and high machine performance. you can use python, scala, java to write your code.